# Java 8 functional programming, collect output of stream which is of type List<MyCustomType>?

Tags: lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I had a simple for loop that is looping over some custom data objects and doing some basic if/else conditional logic and I was trying to write this using stream API/lambas but was running into some issues. This is my code below:

```
private List<MyCustomDataType> myFunction(Object msg) {
        EventGridMessage eventGridMessage = filterData(msg);
        List<RandomDataType> streamList = randomObject.converter(eventGridMessage, logger);

    return streamList.stream().map( i -> {
            List<MyCustomDataType> answer = new ArrayList<>();

            if (i.name != null) {
                if (i.date > 2020) {
               // if in this branch, convert method returns List<MyCustomDataType>
                    answer=  objThatConvertsMsgToMyCustomType.convert(msg);
                }
            }
            else if (i.getdate < 2020) {
               // if in this branch, convert method returns List<MyCustomDataType>
                answer =  objThatConvertsMsgToMyCustomType.convert(msg);
            }

         return answer;
        }).collect();
```

So you can see, I basically want to iterate through this `List` of `RandomDataType` objects (called **streamList**, using stream API, and depending on certain conditions being met in the if/else branches, I want to *add* them to a new List called `answer` that I defined as local in the body of lambda (the `objThatConvertsMsgToMyCustomType.convert(msg)` method returns a new List). *Then*, I simply want to return this List from the method , as it matches my method signature , but was having issues "collecting" this resultant list. I'm assuming my choice of map here is correct vs. `forEach` ,and I thought about using `filter` over my conditionals if/else, but I didn't see how I could do that with the way my logic was branched and the fact it should be returning a `List<>` data type...

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What is `alarmSpans`?

Comment: @Polygnome sorry that was typo. It should have been "streamList"

Comment: Does `objThatConvertsMsgToMyCustomType.convert(msg);` really return a whole list? Because you are not adding to any list, you are replacing the `answer´ list with the return type of that call.

Comment: And where does `msg` come from?

Comment: @Polygnome Yes , `objThatConvertsMsgToMyCustomType.convert(msg)` returns a list of a data type. I just used a generic placeholder for the data type so the problem was simple, I guess you can think of it as a List of "Student' object like `List<Student>`

Comment: @Polygnome I'm not sure if the `msg` is that import to the problem, its just an Object that I convert over to a different data type. It's really JSON String that I am deserializing into java `List<DataType>`

Comment: Is `List<MyCustomDataType>` meant to match `List<MyCustomType>`?

Comment: @Caleth yes.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are producing a `List<List<MyCustomDataType>>`, where you want a `List<MyCustomDataType>`. The simple fix is to use `flatMap`.

I'd rework your `if`s into a filter

```
private List<MyCustomDataType> myFunction(Object msg) {
        EventGridMessage eventGridMessage = filterData(msg);
        List<RandomDataType> items = randomObject.converter(eventGridMessage, logger);

        return items.stream()
            .filter(item -> ((item.name != null) && (item.date > 2020)) || (item.date < 2020))
            .flatMap(objThatConvertsMsgToMyCustomType.convert)
            .collect();
}
```

Comment: why does it produce a List<List<MyCustomDataType>> ?

Comment: `Stream<A>::map(Function<A, B>)` produces a `Stream<B>`, which collects to `List<B>`. You passed a `Function<RandomDataType, List<MyCustomDataType>>`. Substitute `List<MyCustomDataType>` for `B`